# Possible to mass copy timestamps from JXR images to PNG images?

Tags: windows, image, timestamp, metadata

I edited a bunch of JXR images in Photoshop and exported them as PNGs, now all the images I want to upload have incorrect timestamps (the edited date/time). Is there some software out there where I can just copy the timestamps from the JXR files to the PNG?

Alternativly all the images have a timestamp in the name e.g. 23_12_2021 17_35_49, any scripts that could make use of that?

Comment: You can use ExifTool. Read example **exiftool.exe -EXIF:DateTimeOriginal -s -s -s image1.jxr**. Write example: **exiftool.exe -PNG:CreationTime="2002:01:01 01:01:01" image1.png**

Comment: I saw but its just a terminal, not very user friendly. I have over 500 images, I want something that can do them all at once.

Comment: I supposed you write a script to automate these procedures. Something like this PS example:  **(Get-ChildItem D:\0\*.png)|ForEach-Object -Process {$date=(($_.name).Substring(6,19) -replace "_", ":"); Write-Output("exiftool $_.BaseName $date")}**. Or batch-file example: **FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2,3" %%A IN ('DIR /B /W *.png') DO ...**. Where PNG-name would be like this sdfsd 22_12_2021 17_35_49.png*